# How to organize git repository when you need to trace only few files out of 1000?

Tags: git

If someone think topic question is wrong you can edit.

We have quite huge package in here, where only few directories are being modified. I mean that there's plenty of directory paths which have way more files in it, then we actually need to trace with git. So in `api/dir/dir2/contrib/` there are 10 files, and only 2 needs to be traced. we have plenty locations like that, and it's really becomes messy to use gitignore for this. First option was to ignore all files, and `git add` only those files I need to commit with -f flag, this is really annoying to do every time.. Is there's any better solution for organizing such repo?

Comment: Why don't you need to to track the other files? Are they automatically generated or so?

Comment: yes they installed with a package. and they forbidden to be modified anyway. it will create a mess in repo, because we only want to see things that are created by team. all other code hooks are done when installing a package by deb postinstall scripts.

Comment: Could you split package sourced and team sourced files into separate folders?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can ignore everything and add the files you *don't* want to ignore to the `.gitignore` file, prefixed with an exclamation mark.

Example:

```
*
!.gitignore
!foo.txt
```

This would ignore everything except the files `.gitignore` and `foo.txt` in the root folder.

Unfortunatelly, it isn't quite as easy when it comes to files in directories.

Assume I have the following structure:

```
/.gitignore
/foo.txt
/sub/foo.txt
/sub/some_other.txt
/sub2/sub21/bar.txt
/sub2/sub21/some_other2.txt
```

I only want to include `bar.txt` and `foo.txt` and ignore everything else.

`*` ignores everything, so it also ignores subfolders. Simply adding `!sub/foo.txt` is not enough to make git un-ignore that file. What you really have to do is the following:

1. un-ignore `sub`: `!sub/`
2. un-ignore `sub/foo.txt`: `!sub/foo.txt`

This will become very cumbersome if you have a deep directory hierarchy.

To un-ignore `bar.txt`, the following is required:

```
!sub2/
!sub2/sub21/
!sub2/sub21/bar.txt
```

Comment: and what's gonna happen with files that's already in repo? i mean, if they modified `git add` still should be used with `-f` flag? or git will allow to add them without that flag..?

Comment: @holms: Are you talking about files that are already in git and actually shouldn't?

Comment: im talking about files that are in git, and they should be in there. if I'll modify one, to `git add` them to stack, is `-f` flag should be used or not?

Comment: Why should it be used? The file is not ignored, hence the flag is not needed.

Comment: just modified a file in one dir and tried to `git add` it: `The following paths are ignored by one of your .gitignore files: Use -f if you really want to add them.` that file is already in repo so.. that's what im talking about... it's annoying.

Comment: @holms: If you don't want that file to be ignored, perform the steps outlined in my answer for that file.